# Strange login in Chrome

Tags: chrome

I work from home in a company laptop. It has installed this software by the IT team: http://www.misutilities.com/network-asset-tracker-pro/

My main browser is FF and I use Chrome only to test my work. I can tell for sure nobody logged in on it because I was the one to install it and never logged in on it. This morning I found Chrome to be logged in with credentials of one of my colleagues who is in another city. Only option seems to be from remote. But how to know for sure how? Or should I ask him directly? Or the IT team?

I did logout and clear the login info completely.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well my first thing to check would be are you sure you didn't give anyone else even temporary access to your machine? I seems very odd to me for someone to remotely log you in to their google account.

Second solution. It's possible that Google Chrome was originally installed on your machine by somebody else who logged into google chrome, and then when it was uninstalled it failed to clear the saved login data from the last user, meaning that when the program was reinstalled the browser automatically picked up on the saved login data.

Your best bet is to speak to your IT team. It's possible you aren't the first owner of that company laptop and it's extremely possible that it wasn't cleared correctly. It's probably nothing malicious.

With regards to the software that you said was installed on the machine, it looks to me after a brief glance to be a remote monitoring program without the functionality of remote administration, so therefore unlikely it was used in this case.

Comment: Maybe you are right. I am not the first user of this laptop. I wonder if I used this laptop with Chrome logged in for half a year without noticing?

Comment: @Rudy Honestly, stranger things have happened. If you used it as rarely as you said it was unlikely to be something that you would pick up on.